# set new boundary in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, boundary

I have an array:

```
[0.0182, 0.5238, -0.0205, 1.1683, 0.9684, 0.9722, 0.5677, 0.9043, 0.0025, ...
 0.9986, 0.4088, 0.5483, -0.0082, 0.5659]
```

I want to set new numbers in range of `[0 0.5 1]` for the above array. For example, `0.5238` is nearer to `0.5` than `1`, so it should be set to `0.5` rather than `1`. `0.0025` is closer to `0` than `0.5`, so it should be set to `0`, and so on. As a result, new array should be:

```
[0, 0.5, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5]
```

How is it possible in MATLAB? Is there any function?

Comment: This is a little confusing.  Isn't `0.5238` closer to `0.5` than `1`, so it should be set to `0.5`?

Comment: Yes. It should be set to 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is a little bit better than assuming it as simple as 0.5. If you know the values that you want to round closest to.

```
valueToRoundTo = [0,0.5,1];
x = [0.0182, 0.5238, -0.0205, 1.1683, 0.9684, 0.9722, 0.5677, 0.9043, 0.0025, 0.9986, 0.4088, 0.5483, -0.0082, 0.5659];

for i = 1:numel(x)
    [~,idx] = min(abs(valueToRoundTo-x(i)));
    x(i) = valueToRoundTo(idx);
end
```

You can also do this in a very optimized way without the `for loop`

```
valueToRoundTo = [-0.5,0,0.5,1];
x = [0.0182, 0.5238, -0.0205, 1.1683, 0.9684, 0.9722, 0.5677, 0.9043, 0.0025, 0.9986, 0.4088, 0.5483, -0.0082, 0.5659];
[~,idx] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus,x,valueToRoundTo.')));
rounded = valueToRoundTo(idx);
```

Comment: When i set 'valueToRound' to [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], This function works same as when it is [0,0.5,1]. Is it possible to work this function for any round values?

Comment: yes, it is just that none of your values are closer to 0.25 than they are 0 or 0.5, throw a 0.26 in there and you will see it gets rounded properly

Comment: Basically I am just choosing the value that has the smallest absolute difference. Just very optimized and flexible. I recommend using the second solution that uses `bsxfun`. If you want to know more about how that works, read the documentation, just know that it removes the need for the for loop. This will improve performance considerably when working with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to use the `round` function with a scale factor:

```
x = [0.0182, 0.5238, -0.0205, 1.1683, 0.9684, 0.9722, 0.5677, 0.9043, 0.0025, 0.9986, 0.4088, 0.5483, -0.0082, 0.5659]

roundingScaling = 0.5;
round(x/roundingScaling )*roundingScaling
```

Comment: Pretty good and efficient, but I'n not sure that this will be numerically stable for general sets of bounds -particularly those that don't have exact floating-point representations.

Comment: if my new boundary be [0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1]. Does it solution work? I mean, roundingScaling set to 0.25. because of 0.25 distance between numbers.

Comment: @BlueBit.  Yes, it will work as `roundingScaling` is changed.

Comment: Check out my solution below, much simpler, and does not rely on the user changing a scaling factor.